# "You must save the changes before you can convert this activity" on Fax entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

As you can probably take out from the title, I have a problem on my CRM environment converting a fax entity to an incident (case), it is as you know an out of the box functionality. When I press the button on the ribbon to convert it to a case, I'm given the following error: "You must save the changes before you can convert this activity". And I have definitely saved everything before I do this.

I do have the latest rollup and it works for the other activity entities except from this one. Is there any chance someone had similar issues? If so could you share how you resolved this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you customized the Fax entity to with regards to required fields? If so, did you remove any of the 'standard' fields which CRM might require?

Answer (score 0):

There is likely some code running on the form that updates one or more values on the page automatically.  Code like that will cause the form to become "dirty".  Which is what triggers the message you are seeing.

One way to solve it, is modify your code to perform a save after it make its changes.